# Exporting to Excel from SQL Server - BCP Using a Stored Procedure Headers not shown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, bcp

I am running a Stored procedure to export data to an Excel sheet. Issue is that The column headers are being displayed at the bottom or they are missing at times.

What am I missing here ?

SQL Server Version

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-CU7) (KB4024304) - 13.0.2210.0 (X64)
>   Jul 16 2017 17:56:09 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 (Build 9600:
>   ) (Hypervisor)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'rptSalesAndReturnBCP' AND Type = 'P')
BEGIN
    DROP PROC [dbo].[rptSalesAndReturnBCP] 
END

GO
CREATE PROC [dbo].[rptSalesAndReturnBCP]
    @StartDate DATETIME
    ,@EndDate DATETIME
    ,@BusinessChannelUID INT = NULL
    ,@DistributorUID INT = NULL
    ,@GEmployeeUID INT = NULL
    ,@GAgentUID INT = NULL
    ,@SalesOrgID NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,@Output_Number INT OUTPUT
    ,@Output_FileName VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)    

    --Create User Session Tempory table     
    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR (255) 
    SET @TableName='##'  + REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(MAX)) +'_TableRSA','-','');
    PRINT @TableName
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled Filter

    DECLARE @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled BIT

    SELECT @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = BC.IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled
    FROM BusinessChannel BC
    WHERE BC.UID = @BusinessChannelUID
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- NSM, RSM, ASM, ASE login filter

    DECLARE @mpt_DesignationEnum INT = 0, @mpt_DesignationUID INT

    SELECT @mpt_DesignationEnum = EB.mpt_DesignationEnum, @mpt_DesignationUID = EB.mpt_DesignationUID
    FROM EmployeeBusinessChannel EB 
    WHERE EB.BusinessChannelUID = @BusinessChannelUID 
        AND EB.EmployeeUID = @GEmployeeUID

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Sales Org

    IF (@SalesOrgID IS NULL 
        OR @SalesOrgID = '-1'
        OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM BusinessChannelSalesOrg WHERE BussinessChannelUID = @BusinessChannelUID GROUP BY BussinessChannelUID HAVING COUNT(1) > 1))
    BEGIN
        SET @SalesOrgID = NULL;
    END

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Agency Manager

    DECLARE @IsAgencyManagerFilter BIT = 0
    CREATE TABLE #AgencyUIDs (UID INT)  

    IF (@mpt_DesignationEnum = 90)
    BEGIN
        SET @IsAgencyManagerFilter = 1;

        INSERT INTO #AgencyUIDs
        SELECT P.ParentUID
        FROM ParentChildLink P
            INNER JOIN Agent A ON P.ChildUID = A.UID
        WHERE A.EmployeeUID = @GEmployeeUID
            AND P.mpt_TypeEnum = 3
            AND P.ExpiryDate IS NULL
            AND A.ExpiryDate IS NULL
    END

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Sales Reps

    DECLARE @IsSalesRepFilter BIT = 0
    CREATE TABLE #SalesRepUIDs (UID INT PRIMARY KEY);

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MultipurposeTag WHERE UID = @mpt_DesignationUID AND Flag2 = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @IsSalesRepFilter = 1;

        INSERT INTO #SalesRepUIDs
        SELECT DISTINCT emp_SalesRepUID
        FROM EmployeeSalesRep
        WHERE ExpiryDate IS NULL
            AND emp_ParentUID = @GEmployeeUID
            AND (@SalesOrgID IS NULL OR SalesOrg = @SalesOrgID);
    END

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Distributors

    CREATE TABLE #DistributorUIDs (DistributorUID INT PRIMARY KEY)
    DECLARE @IsDistributorFilter BIT = 0

    IF @DistributorUID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @IsDistributorFilter = 1;
        INSERT INTO #DistributorUIDs VALUES (@DistributorUID)
    END
    ELSE IF (@IsSalesRepFilter = 0 AND (@mpt_DesignationEnum = 5 OR @mpt_DesignationEnum = 6 OR @mpt_DesignationEnum = 7 OR @mpt_DesignationEnum = 8))
    BEGIN
        SET @IsDistributorFilter = 1;

        INSERT INTO #DistributorUIDs(DistributorUID)
        SELECT ED.DistributorUID
        FROM EmployeeDistributor ED 
        WHERE ED.EmployeeUID = @GEmployeeUID
            AND ED.BusinessChannelUID = @BusinessChannelUID
    END

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SET @Query= 'SELECT  * INTO  '+@TableName+'
    FROM
    (
            SELECT D.Name AS Distributor
            , D.ID AS DistributorID
            , RE.Description AS Region
            , TE.Description AS Territory
            , T.ID AS TxnID
            , ISNULL(T.TxnInvoiceSerialNo,''-'') AS SerialNo
            , T.Date AS Date 
            , DATEPART(yyyy,T.Date) AS Year
            , DATEPART(mm,T.Date) AS Month
            , DATEPART(dd,T.Date) AS Day
            , O.Name AS Outlet
            , O.ID AS OutletID
            , ISNULL(MPT2.MiscData,''-'') AS OutletType
            , ISNULL(MPT3.MiscData,''-'') AS OutletGroup
            , CASE WHEN (E.FirstName + '' '' + E.LastName) IS NULL THEN ''* UNASSIGNED *'' ELSE E.FirstName + '' '' + E.LastName END + '' - '' + A.MiscData  as Agent   
            , CASE WHEN (ASM.FirstName + '' '' + ASM.LastName) IS NULL THEN ''* UNASSIGNED *'' ELSE ASM.FirstName + '' '' + ASM.LastName END as ASMName                 
            , CASE WHEN R.UID IS NULL THEN R2.Description ELSE R.Description END AS Route
            , ISNULL(C1.Description, '') AS Category1
            , ISNULL(C2.Description, '') AS Category2
            , ISNULL(C3.Description, '') AS Category3
            , ISNULL(C4.Description, '') AS Category4
            , ISNULL(C5.Description, '') AS Category5
            , I.ID AS ItemID
            , I.Description AS Item
            , ISNULL(MPT1.MiscData,''-'') AS Team
            , '' AS Reason
            , SO.Description AS SalesOrgName
            , I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack
            ,CASE WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 1 THEN TL.UnitQty / I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack 
                  WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 0 THEN 0 END AS Cases -- Cases Not Allowed
            ,CASE WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 1 THEN TL.UnitQty % I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack 
                  WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 0 THEN TL.UnitQty END AS Units -- Cases Not Allowed
            ,CASE WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 1 THEN TL.FreeQty / I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack
                  WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 0 THEN 0 END AS FreeCases -- Cases Not Allowed
            ,CASE WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 1 THEN TL.FreeQty % I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack
                  WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 0 THEN TL.FreeQty END AS FreeUnits -- Cases Not Allowed
            , (TL.UnitQty * I.Volume / 1000000) AS Tonnage
            , TL.UnitPrice AS Price
            , TL.GrossValue AS GrossValue
            , TL.LineDisc AS GrossValue
            , TL.AdditionalDisc AS AdditionalDisc
            , CASE WHEN O.mpt_TypeEnum = 1 THEN (ISNULL(TL.GrossValue,0)) - (ISNULL(TL.LineDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) + ((ISNULL(TL.NetSaleValue,0) - (ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0))) * (ISNULL(T.CompanyDiscPct,0) / 100)) + (ISNULL(TL.GrossValue,0) -(ISNULL(TL.LineDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) )) * (ISNULL(T.DocDiscPct,0) / 100)) 
                   WHEN O.mpt_TypeEnum = 2 THEN (ISNULL(TL.GrossValue,0) -(ISNULL(TL.LineDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) )) END  AS NetValue 
            , (ISNULL(TL.GrossValue,0) -(ISNULL(TL.LineDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0)  + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0)  )) * (ISNULL(T.DocDiscPct,0) / 100) AS Discount
            , ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0) AS GroupDiscPart
            , ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) AS AddiLineDisc
            , ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) AS AddiGroupDisc
            , (TL.NetSaleValue - (TL.GroupDiscPart + TL.AdditionalGroupDisc)) * (ISNULL(T.CompanyDiscPct,0) / 100) AS CompanyLineDisc
            , AR1.Description AS Town
            , AR2.Description AS Area
            , AR3.Description AS BusinessArea
            , ''Sales'' AS TypeTxn
            , CASE WHEN TL.mpt_TypeEnum = 1 THEN ''Normal Sales'' ELSE ''Free Sales'' END AS LineType
            , CASE WHEN O.mpt_TypeEnum = 1 THEN ''Normal'' WHEN O.mpt_TypeEnum = 2 THEN ''Direct'' END AS OutletBusinessType
            , MPT4.MiscData AS Type
            , CASE WHEN IPL1.UnitListPrice IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE IPL1.UnitListPrice END AS p1
            , CASE WHEN IPL2.UnitListPrice IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE IPL2.UnitListPrice END AS p2
            , CASE WHEN IPL3.UnitListPrice IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE IPL3.UnitListPrice END AS p3
            , AG.Name AS AgencyName 
            , CASE WHEN ISNULL(T.IsQuatationCompleted,0) = 0 AND T.mpt_TypeEnum = 58 THEN ''Quotation'' ELSE ''Normal Invoice'' END as InvoiceType
        FROM TxnInvoice T
            INNER JOIN TxnInvoiceLine TL ON T.UID = TL.TxnInvoiceUID AND T.SiteUID = TL.TxnInvoice_SiteUID
            INNER JOIN Item I ON TL.ItemUID = I.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Agency AG ON I.AgencyUID = AG.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Call C ON T.Call_SiteUID = C.SiteUID AND T.CallUID = C.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            ( 
                SELECT MAX(R.RouteUID) AS RouteUID, R.OutletUID 
                FROM RouteOutlet R
                WHERE R.ExpiryDate IS NULL
                GROUP BY R.OutletUID
            ) KK ON T.OutletUID = KK.OutletUID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Route R ON C.RouteUID = R.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Route R2 ON KK.RouteUID = R2.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesOrg SO ON SO.ID = T.SalesOrgID
            LEFT JOIN Category C1 ON I.CategoryUID2 = C1.UID
            LEFT JOIN Category C2 ON I.CategoryUID3 = C2.UID
            LEFT JOIN Category C3 ON I.CategoryUID4 = C3.UID
            LEFT JOIN Category C4 ON I.CategoryUID5 = C4.UID
            LEFT JOIN Category C5 ON I.CategoryUID6 = C5.UID
            LEFT JOIN Outlet O ON T.OutletUID = O.UID
            LEFT JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT1 ON I.MPTSubTypeUID = MPT1.UID
            LEFT JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT2 ON O.mpt_TypeUID = MPT2.UID
            LEFT JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT3 ON O.mpt_GroupUID = MPT3.UID
            LEFT JOIN Area AR1 ON O.AreaUID = AR1.UID
            LEFT JOIN Area AR2 ON AR1.ParentUID = AR2.UID
            LEFT JOIN Area AR3 ON O.BusinessAreaUID = AR3.UID
            LEFT JOIN Agent A ON T.AgentUID = A.UID
            INNER JOIN Distributor D ON T.DistributorUID = D.UID
            INNER JOIN EmployeeDistributor ED ON D.UID = ED.DistributorUID
            INNER JOIN EmployeeBusinessChannel EBC ON ED.EmployeeUID = EBC.EmployeeUID AND EBC.mpt_DesignationEnum = 6 -- ASM
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee ASM ON EBC.EmployeeUID = ASM.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Area RE ON D.RegionUID = RE.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Area TE ON D.BusinessAreaUID = TE.UID
            LEFT JOIN ItemPriceList IPL1 ON TL.ItemPriceListUID1 = IPL1.UID
            LEFT JOIN ItemPriceList IPL2 ON TL.ItemPriceListUID2 = IPL2.UID
            LEFT JOIN ItemPriceList IPL3 ON TL.ItemPriceListUID3 = IPL3.UID
            LEFT JOIN Employee E ON T.EmployeeUID = E.UID
            LEFT JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT4 ON T.mpt_TypeUID = MPT4.UID
        WHERE T.mpt_TypeEnum IN ( 21 , 44, 14, 1)
            AND T.ExpiryDate IS NULL
            AND T.SubmittedDate IS NOT NULL
            AND T.Date >= @StartDate
            AND T.Date <= @EndDate
            AND D.BusinessChannelUID = @BusinessChannelUID
            AND (@SalesOrgID IS NULL OR SO.ID = @SalesOrgID)
            AND (@IsDistributorFilter = 0 OR D.UID IN (SELECT DistributorUID FROM #DistributorUIDs))
            AND (@IsAgencyManagerFilter = 0 OR I.AgencyUID IN (SELECT UID FROM #AgencyUIDs))
            AND (@IsSalesRepFilter = 0 OR T.EmployeeUID IN (SELECT UID FROM #SalesRepUIDs))

        UNION ALL

        SELECT D.Name AS Distributor
            , D.ID AS DistributorID
            , RE.Description AS Region
            , TE.Description AS Territory
            , T.ID AS TxnID
            , ISNULL(T.SerialNo,''-'') AS SerialNo
            , T.Date AS Date
            , DATEPART(yyyy,T.Date) AS Year
            , DATEPART(mm,T.Date) AS Month
            , DATEPART(dd,T.Date) AS Day
            , O.Name AS Outlet
            , O.ID AS OutletID
            , ISNULL(MPT2.MiscData,''-'') AS OutletType
            , ISNULL(MPT3.MiscData,''-'') AS OutletGroup
            , CASE WHEN (E.FirstName + '' '' + E.LastName) IS NULL THEN ''* UNASSIGNED *'' ELSE E.FirstName + '' '' + E.LastName END + '' - '' + A.MiscData  as Agent   
            , CASE WHEN (ASM.FirstName + '' '' + ASM.LastName) IS NULL THEN ''* UNASSIGNED *'' ELSE ASM.FirstName + '' '' + ASM.LastName END as ASMName
            , CASE WHEN R.UID IS NULL THEN R2.Description ELSE R.Description END AS Route
            , ISNULL(C1.Description, '') AS Category1
            , ISNULL(C2.Description, '') AS Category2
            , ISNULL(C3.Description, '') AS Category3
            , ISNULL(C4.Description, '') AS Category4
            , ISNULL(C5.Description, '') AS Category5
            , I.ID AS ItemID
            , I.Description AS Item
            , ISNULL(MPT1.MiscData,''-'') AS Team
            , MPT1.MiscData AS Reason
            , SO.Description AS SalesOrgName
            , I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack
            ,CASE WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 1 THEN -TL.UnitQty / I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack 
                  WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 0 THEN 0 END AS Cases -- Cases Not Allowed
            ,CASE WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 1 THEN -TL.UnitQty % I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack 
                  WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 0 THEN -TL.UnitQty END AS Units -- Cases Not Allowed
            ,CASE WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 1 THEN -TL.FreeQty / I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack
                  WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 0 THEN 0 END AS FreeCases -- Cases Not Allowed
            ,CASE WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 1 THEN -TL.FreeQty % I.UnitsPerBulk1Pack
                  WHEN @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = 0 THEN -TL.FreeQty END AS FreeUnits -- Cases Not Allowed
            , -(TL.UnitQty * I.Volume / 1000000) AS Tonnage
            , TL.UnitPrice AS Price
            , -TL.GrossValue AS GrossValue
            , -TL.LineDisc AS LineDisc
            , -TL.AdditionalDisc AS AdditionalDisc
            , CASE WHEN O.mpt_TypeEnum = 1 THEN -(ISNULL(TL.GrossValue,0) - (ISNULL(TL.LineDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) + (TL.GrossValue -(ISNULL(TL.LineDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) )) * (ISNULL(T.DocDiscPct,0) / 100) + (ISNULL(TL.NetReturnValue,0) * (ISNULL(T.CompanyDiscPct,0) / 100)))) 
                   WHEN O.mpt_TypeEnum = 2 THEN -(TL.GrossValue -(ISNULL(TL.LineDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0)   + ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) )) END  AS NetValue 
            , -(ISNULL(TL.GrossValue,0) -(ISNULL(TL.LineDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) + ISNULL(TL.GroupDiscPart,0)  + ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) )) * (ISNULL(T.DocDiscPct,0) / 100) AS Discount
            , -ISNULL(GroupDiscPart,0) AS GroupDiscPart
            , -ISNULL(TL.AdditionalDisc,0) AS AddiLineDisc
            , -ISNULL(TL.AdditionalGroupDisc,0) AS AddiGroupDisc
            , -((TL.NetReturnValue - (TL.GroupDiscPart + TL.AdditionalGroupDisc)) * (ISNULL(T.CompanyDiscPct,0) / 100)) AS CompanyLineDisc
            , AR1.Description AS Town
            , AR2.Description AS Area
            , AR3.Description AS BusinessArea
            , CASE WHEN T.mpt_TypeEnum <> 35 THEN ''Return'' ELSE ''Replacement'' END AS TypeTxn
            , CASE WHEN ISNULL(TL.FreeQty,0) > 0 THEN ''Free Return'' ELSE ''Normal Return'' END AS LineType
            , CASE WHEN O.mpt_TypeEnum = 1 THEN ''Normal'' WHEN O.mpt_TypeEnum = 2 THEN ''Direct'' END AS OutletBusinessType
            , MPT4.MiscData AS Type
            , CASE WHEN IPL1.UnitListPrice IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE IPL1.UnitListPrice END AS p1
            , CASE WHEN IPL2.UnitListPrice IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE IPL2.UnitListPrice END AS p2
            , CASE WHEN IPL3.UnitListPrice IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE IPL3.UnitListPrice END AS p3
            , AG.Name AS AgencyName 
            , '' as InvoiceType
        FROM TxnReturn T
            INNER JOIN TxnReturnLine TL ON T.UID = TL.TxnReturnUID AND T.SiteUID = TL.TxnReturn_SiteUID
            INNER JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT1 ON TL.mpt_ReturnReasonUID = MPT1.UID
            INNER JOIN Item I ON TL.ItemUID = I.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Agency AG ON I.AgencyUID = AG.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Call C ON T.Call_SiteUID = C.SiteUID AND T.CallUID = C.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            ( 
                SELECT MAX(R.RouteUID) AS RouteUID,R.OutletUID 
                FROM RouteOutlet R
                WHERE R.ExpiryDate IS NULL
                GROUP BY R.OutletUID
            ) KK ON T.OutletUID = KK.OutletUID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Route R ON C.RouteUID = R.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Route R2 ON KK.RouteUID = R2.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesOrg SO ON SO.ID = T.SalesOrgID
            LEFT JOIN Category C1 ON I.CategoryUID2 = C1.UID
            LEFT JOIN Category C2 ON I.CategoryUID3 = C2.UID
            LEFT JOIN Category C3 ON I.CategoryUID4 = C3.UID
            LEFT JOIN Category C4 ON I.CategoryUID5 = C4.UID
            LEFT JOIN Category C5 ON I.CategoryUID6 = C5.UID
            LEFT JOIN Outlet O ON T.OutletUID = O.UID
            LEFT JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT2 ON I.MPTSubTypeUID = MPT2.UID
            LEFT JOIN Area AR1 ON O.AreaUID = AR1.UID
            LEFT JOIN Area AR2 ON AR1.ParentUID = AR2.UID
            LEFT JOIN Area AR3 ON O.BusinessAreaUID = AR3.UID
            INNER JOIN Agent A ON T.AgentUID = A.UID
            LEFT JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT3 ON O.mpt_TypeUID = MPT3.UID
            LEFT JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT4 ON O.mpt_GroupUID = MPT4.UID
            LEFT JOIN ItemPriceList IPL1 ON TL.ItemPriceListUID1 = IPL1.UID
            LEFT JOIN ItemPriceList IPL2 ON TL.ItemPriceListUID2 = IPL2.UID
            LEFT JOIN ItemPriceList IPL3 ON TL.ItemPriceListUID3 = IPL3.UID
            INNER JOIN Distributor D ON T.DistributorUID = D.UID
            INNER JOIN EmployeeDistributor ED ON D.UID = ED.DistributorUID
            INNER JOIN EmployeeBusinessChannel EBC ON ED.EmployeeUID = EBC.EmployeeUID AND EBC.mpt_DesignationEnum = 6 -- ASM
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee ASM ON EBC.EmployeeUID = ASM.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Area RE ON D.RegionUID = RE.UID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Area TE ON D.BusinessAreaUID = TE.UID
            LEFT JOIN Employee E ON A.EmployeeUID = E.UID
            LEFT JOIN MultiPurposeTag MPT5 ON T.mpt_TypeUID = MPT5.UID
        WHERE 
            T.mpt_TypeEnum IN (57,2,45, 35/*Replacement*/)
            AND T.ExpiryDate IS NULL
            AND T.SubmittedDate IS NOT NULL
            AND T.Date >= @StartDate
            AND T.Date <= @EndDate
            AND (@IsDistributorFilter = 0 OR D.UID IN (SELECT DistributorUID FROM #DistributorUIDs))
            AND (@BusinessChannelUID IS NULL OR D.BusinessChannelUID = @BusinessChannelUID)
            AND (@SalesOrgID IS NULL OR SO.ID = @SalesOrgID)
            AND (@IsAgencyManagerFilter = 0 OR I.AgencyUID IN (SELECT UID FROM #AgencyUIDs))
            AND (@IsSalesRepFilter = 0 OR T.EmployeeUID IN (SELECT UID FROM #SalesRepUIDs))

)'

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXEC sp_executesql 
            @Query
            , N'@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @BusinessChannelUID INT, @DistributorUID INT, @SalesOrgID NVARCHAR(50), @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled BIT
            , @mpt_DesignationEnum INT, @mpt_DesignationUID INT, @IsAgencyManagerFilter BIT, @IsSalesRepFilter BIT, @IsDistributorFilter BIT'
            ,@StartDate = @StartDate
            ,@EndDate = @EndDate
            ,@BusinessChannelUID = @BusinessChannelUID
            ,@DistributorUID = @DistributorUID
            --,@GEmployeeUID = @GEmployeeUID
            --,@AgencyUID = @AgencyUID
            ,@SalesOrgID = @SalesOrgID
            ,@IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled = @IsItemBulk1QtyEnabled
            ,@mpt_DesignationEnum = @mpt_DesignationEnum
            ,@mpt_DesignationUID = @mpt_DesignationUID
            ,@IsAgencyManagerFilter = @IsAgencyManagerFilter
            ,@IsSalesRepFilter = @IsSalesRepFilter
            ,@IsDistributorFilter = @IsDistributorFilter
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @server Varchar (100)
    SET @server = 'SERVERNAME'
    DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @ToDayDate VARCHAR(12)
    SELECT @ToDayDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)
    SET @Output_FIleName = CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(MAX))+ '_SalesAndReturnsRpt' + '.xls'

      DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR (4000)
      SET @FilePath = '\\SERVERNAME\BCPDumpFiles\' + @Output_FIleName  ;

    DECLARE @ExcSql Varchar (Max)
        DECLARE @dbName Varchar (100)
        SET @dbName = 'master'
        DECLARE @sql varchar (8000)
        SET @sql = ' SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName ;
        --exec(@sql)

        DECLARE @dbName1 Varchar (100)
        SELECT  @dbName1 = @dbName
        SELECT  @dbName = 'use ' + @dbName + ';'

        --Prepare Columns as excel compatible 
        DECLARE @columnNames varchar (8000), @columnConvert varchar (8000), @tempSQL varchar (8000)

        SELECT  @columnNames = COALESCE(@columnNames + ',', '') + '"' + column_name + '"',
        @columnConvert = COALESCE(@columnConvert + ',', '') + 'convert(nvarchar(4000),'
            + '[' + column_name + ']' + CASE
                WHEN data_type IN ('datetime', 'smalldatetime') THEN ',121'
                WHEN data_type IN ('numeric', 'decimal') THEN ',128'
                WHEN data_type IN ('float', 'real', 'money', 'smallmoney') THEN ',2'
                WHEN data_type IN ('datetime', 'smalldatetime') THEN ',120' ELSE ''
            END + ') as ' + '[' + column_name + ']'
        FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
        WHERE table_name = @TableName

        print @columnNames
        print @TableName
            --Prepare sql to bcp 
        SELECT  @sql = 'select ' + @columnNames + ' into '+@TableName+'_2 from (select ' + @columnConvert + ', 
            ''2'' as temp##SortID         
                from '+@TableName+' union all select ''' + REPLACE(@columnNames, ',', ''', ''') + ''', 
                    ''1'') t order by temp##SortID'        
        EXEC (@sql)
        print @sql
        SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM '+ @TableName +'_2'
        PRINT @Sql
        exec(@sql)

        SET @sql = 'bcp " select * from '+@TableName+'_2 order by [Year] asc "  queryout "' + @FilePath + '" -U uno -P uno   -c -T -S ' + @server   
        PRINT @Sql
        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql

        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  SET  @Query = N'DROP TABLE ' + @TableName ;
        --EXEC sp_sqlexec @Query
        --SET  @Query = N'DROP TABLE ' + @TableName + '_2' ;
        --EXEC sp_sqlexec @Query    

        SET @OutPut_Number = 1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorDescription VARCHAR(1000) = 'ERROR - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() RAISERROR(@ErrorDescription,16,1)
    SET @OutPut_Number = 2
    --SELECT @ErrorDescription
END CATCH
```